# There's a small detail in this proof on why $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ that I can't figure out

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, polylogarithm

http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/2/Kalman-2013.pdf

Here is a link to the article I have been reading. It's really interesting and easy to follow. What bothers me is a result the author uses. On page 45, the author goes on to say that $\ln(-1) = i\pi$ because $e^{i\pi} = -1$. Just take $\ln$ to both sides. Then he substitutes that result in and gets $\displaystyle\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Makes sense. Here is my problem. Technically $e^{3i\pi}$ is also equal to $-1$ but if we were to substitute it in, we would not get the correct solution. So I guess my question is, does using other forms of $e^{i\pi}$ like $e^{3i\pi}$ work or is there a reason why you can only choose $e^{i\pi}$?

Comment: This is answered in the "Making the proof rigorous" section. Basically, to define natural log on complex numbers, you have to "pick a branch."

Comment: Picking a branch when more than one branch exists is, in and of itself, an arbitrary decision. This does not answer the question, it only reiterates the question in a different form. How do you decide on the branch?

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum, I think what Grumpy Parsnip was saying is that the procedure for selecting the branch is laid out in the section on rigor.  That said, I wonder if you couldn't just say $\ln(-1)$ has to be *some* odd multiple of $i\pi$, conclude that the result is an odd square multiple of $\pi^2/6$, and then observe that $1+1/4+1/9+\cdots$ is obviously less than $2$, so the odd square multiple can only be $1$.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum While your ocncern has some validity, one of the Bernoulli's already showed that the sum of the series is less than 2. That was before Euler came up with the exact answer. Bernoulli compared the series in question with another series (having greater terms) that telescopes to 2. And then with Barry's answer, the branch choice makes perfect sense.

Comment: Yes, I saw Barry's answer. I can appreciate that perspective. I just think it needed mention in the proof, instead of just saying "pick a branch".

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: I was not purporting to give an argument, just summarizing what to expect when you read the "making the proof rigorous" section of the referenced document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general one can't take a logarithm of a negative number (This is at least the way we see it in calculus). One can extend the logarithm so that one can take the logarithm of a negative number; in fact one can take a logarithm of any non-zero complex number. But this depends on definition.

[A standard way to define this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value) is to say that 
$$
\log(z) = \ln\lvert z \rvert + i Arg(z).
$$

With this definition
$$
\log(-1) = \ln(1) + i(\pi) = i\pi.
$$

Comment: This answer is not completely satisfactory, you've just pushed back the question: Before it was "why is $\ln{(-1)}=i\pi$?", now it's "why is $\text{Arg}{(-1)}=i\pi$?". Choosing $\text{Arg}(-1)=-i\pi$, say, seems just as reasonable.

Comment: @WillR: Apparently the OP thought it was enough since he accepted the answer. If you want, you could ask a new question about this. That said,  $Arg(-1) = \pi$ is just the definition of the of the argument of a complex number. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29 for more on this.

Comment: That's interesting; if I recall correctly, in my Complex Functions module in university the value of $\text{Arg}$ was intentionally left undefined on the non-positive real axis, precisely because the choice is arbitrary. Of course, $\pi$ is probably the most sensible of the choices, but, again, I don't know of a convincing reason for this.

Comment: @WillR: Which is why you could consider asking the question as a new question (after you have determined that it hasn't already been asked of course).

Answer (score 2):

the first section of note is only the outlook of proof and in page 46 (***Making the Proof Rigorous***) the author has mentioned that the branch $r>0$ , $-\pi<\theta\le\pi$ has been used.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series
$$\log(1+z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}z^k}{k}$$
is only valid for the principal branch of the logarithm.